# Visual Studio No Longer Goes to the Method Definition

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I miss being able to hit F12 and going to the definition of a method. Because my solution consists of like four separate projects, when I hit F12 and the method (or property, or whatever) is in another project, it opens up the completely worthless object browser. Is there some setting I can fix so that it will just go to the correct file and method? Or am I pretty much SOL...

Thanks

Comment: This question is not off-topic here, but I suspect you'll find more Visual Studio users on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @carlf i thought about that but figured it would be redirected here because it's not "programming related"

Answer (score 4):

This still works for me. It may be you installed an addon/extension which remapped F12.

To reset it, you can go to`Tools > Customize` then click the button at the bottom of the dialog which says `Keyboard...`. In the dialog that comes up, type `Edit.GoToDefinition` in the `Show commands containing:` textbox.

Set `Use new shortcut in:` to `Global`.
Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in the `Press shortcut keys:` textbox.
Click `Assign`.

You can then OK your way out of the dialogs, and that should restore the functionality.

Comment: Doesn't work :\ The F12 key works when you're looking for a definition within the same project, but when you are looking for a definition in a different project (still within the same solution, of course), it just opens the object browser.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it here. I have a solution which has about a dozen different projects in it. I went to a file in one project which references a class in another project, highlighted it, clicked `F12` and it took me to the class file. It may depend on whether, when you added the reference to project A in project B, if you selected project A in the `Projects` tab or the `Assemblies` tab of the `Add Reference` dialog.

Comment: in my references, the projects are referenced for both of the other projects :\

Answer (score 3):

I found that if the reference project targets a different framework (ie my application is 4.0, but my model in 3.5), F12 goes to the object browser.

When the reference targets the same framework, F12 works . . .

Comment: interesting. i'll check this out. thanks for the answer.. this still doesn't work for me to this day!

Comment: Upvoted as this was exactly the problem I was having. VS2008 imported .NET 3.5 class library but website was built from scratch as .NET 4 website. Changed class libraries to v4 and F12/go to definition works fine

Answer (score 2):

I found that a recently installed code productivity tool (Telerik JustCode) had hijacked the F12 hotkey.  F12(Global) **was still associated** with GoTo Definition, but apparently the F12(Edit) was taking precedence. There was something wrong with my JustCode install, so it was not working, and F12 utlimately no longer worked.

Since I wasn't really using JustCode, I uninstalled it. After doing this, F12 began to do what it was supposed to do.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i will try this out when i get home!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have added a binary file (dll) as your Reference. Try the following in Solution Explorer: 
(1) under your client project, expand References
(2) locate and remove the reference to the class containing your method/property
(3) under the same client project, add new References
(4) click on the "Projects" tab in the "Add Reference" dialog
I am assuming that your Solution includes both projects.

Comment: tried it... still goes to the object browser. wtf

Comment: hmmm... sorry to hear... just for the heck of it, can you repeat the same steps, but this time save your client project after removing the reference (step 2) and then restart (close and open) Visual Studio and continue with steps 3 and 4. (if you attempt to compile between 3 and 4, you will get a lot of Errors, but this would only be temporary)

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, when you right click on the properties and methods and choose "Go To Definition", do you get the same behavior as "F12"?

Comment: @arun yes, i get the same behavior when i right click and hit go to definition and F12. it's suuuuper frustrating

Comment: Usually when you add a Project Reference (instead of a dll Reference) into a consuming Project, the project file will hold the information that the referenced module is a Project available in the solution and not the binary. Try to open the consuming Project in Notepad (or any text editor) and search for the referenced module. If you see that under a "Reference" tag (like in "&lt;Reference Include=yourDll&gt;", there lies your problem. Just remove it and add this:under

Comment: Just remove it and add this:
<ProjectReference Include="relativepathtoyourProject\projectfilename">
      <Project>GUIDofyourProject(you can get this from solution file)</Project>
      <Name>nameofyourproject</Name>
</ProjectReference>
under ItemGroup that contains other ProjectReferences (if there is none, add a new ItemGroup tag and embed this)

Comment: Just to be safe, backup your project file, before you make these changes, - just an exit strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. removing and adding the reference solved it for me. for more details you can refer to [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837037/go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-only-brings-up-the-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different from the OP's question but my ability to Go To Definition was suddenly non-existent. I use Resharper so I thought maybe the issue was there.

In the end, I just had to close and re-open Visual Studio.

Hope it helps someone. . .